# Postgres: Erro 28P01 e um usuário não chamado

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Tenho uma aplicação NodeJS rodando ok na minha máquina, mas em produção apresenta um comportamento estranho: ele pede por um usuário que eu não chamei!

Aqui o meu arquivo .env:

```
PGUSER=postgres
PGHOST=my.domain
PGPASSWORD=my.passwd
PGDATABASE=my.dbase
PGPORT=5432
```

Como eu disse, roda ok na minha máquina mas quando eu mando rodar no ambiente do meu VPS AWS Lighsail, ele quebra:

```
/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287
        const message = name === 'notice' ? new messages_1.NoticeMessage(length, messageValue) : new messages_1.DatabaseError(messageValue, length, name);
                                                                                                 ^

error: password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 102,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '330',
  routine: 'auth_failed'
}
```

O que é estranho: eu não chamo o usuário "ubuntu" no meu código - eu chamo o "postgres", como está no meu arquivo .env. Eu até tentei criar um usuário "ubuntu" no POstgres e testei o acesso com ele no PGAdmin e no BeeKeeper, em ambos eu consegui acesso, mas não cosigo fazer minha aplicação acessar, nem com "postgres" nem com "ubuntu".

Meu arquivo pg_hba.conf:

```
local all     postgres   peer
local all     ubuntu     trust
local all     all                 md5
host  all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5
```

Meu arquivo de conexão:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const conecta = new Pool({
    user: process.env.PGUSER,
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
    host: process.env.PGHOST,
    port: process.env.PGPORT
});

module.exports = conecta;
```

Why it insists in "ubuntu" user? And why my NodeJS app can't connect if PgAdmin and BeeKeeper done it?

Pq ele insiste em tentar com o usuário "ubuntu"? E pq minha palicação NOde não consegue acesse mas o PGAdmin e o Beekeeper conseguem?

Comment: poderia fazer um console.log na variável `process.env.PGUSER`, estou supondo que em seu VPS o arquivo `.env` não existe no ambiente da VPS. Por causa da mensagem de erro.

Comment: ah sim, o local para fazer o console.log dessa variaável é logo após o comando `require('dotenv').config();` em seu código.

Comment: Rolou um "undefined" - realmente não estava chamando o .env

Aí eu tirei o .env da raiz do projeto e joguei dentro do /src - ai rolou...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela mensagem de erro que postou, o arquivo `.env` não parece estar no diretório correto.

Uma maneira de depurar se o seu arquivo `.env` está carregando as variáveis de ambiente devidamente é utilizando o `console.log`.

Para fazer essa verificação e confirmar se os valores estão sendo carregados devidamente, faça o seguinte, adicione um `console.log` da sua variável `process.env`.

Segue um exemplo de como deve ficar:

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env) // remova após confirmar que está funcionando
```

Verifique se os valores estão sendo carregados do arquivo `.env` corretamente.

### Não tenho certeza qual o diretório devo colocar o meu arquivo `.env`

Neste caso a melhor abordagem é passar um caminho absoluto da localização do seu arquivo `.env`. É possível passar o caminho absoluto para o seu arquivo `.env` passando como argumento o valor `path` para a função ***config()***, da seguinte forma:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/caminho/para/seu/.env' });
```

### O problema ainda persiste

Neste caso a melhor solução é ligar o modo debug da lib `'dotenv'`.

Isso é possível da seguinte forma:

```
require('dotenv').config({ debug: true });
```

Assim terá mensagens mais inteligíveis de onde procurar pelo erro e identificar qual a causa raiz do problema.

Eu simulei um problema em minha aplicação, aqui eu removi o arquivo .env do diretório correto. E esta foi a mensagem que apareceu quando eu habilitei o modo debug.

> [dotenv][DEBUG] Failed to load /home/usuario/app/.env ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/usuario/app/.env'

Todas as informações contidas aqui estão disponíveis na documentação da biblioteca [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)